# I'm a beginner programmer, and I need to inquire about return statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm having some troubles with making a guessing game function that keeps score of how many times you get it correct. I currently have two problems:

1. The code causes the function to activate twice, is there any way to both print a function's returned value and assign a variable to it?
2. The variable "score" never goes beyond 1 because if the number you guess is wrong, the function returns none and goes back to 0

Here is my code, it's a mess:

```
def GuessingGame(score):

    rng = random.Random()
    numbertoguess = rng.randrange(1,10)
    guess = int(input ("What is your guess for a number between 1 and 10?"))
    if numbertoguess == guess:
        print ("Great guess! You're correct.")
        int (score = score + 1)
        return score
    else:
        print ("Wrong, the number was "+str(numbertoguess)+".")

playagain = "yes"

score = 0

while playagain == "yes":

    print ("The score is now "+str(GuessingGame(score))+".")
    score = GuessingGame(score)
    playagain = input ("Play again? (yes or no)")
    if playagain != "yes":
        print ("Goodbye")
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is actually calling the function:

```
print ("The score is now "+str(GuessingGame(score))+".")
```

You should just use:

```
print ("The score is now "+ str(score) +".")
```

`score` is a variable, and can be used as such

To answer the second question, you are not `return`ing in the `else:` clause.

Instead of this:

```
if numbertoguess == guess:
    print ("Great guess! You're correct.")
    int (score = score + 1)
    return score
else:
    print ("Wrong, the number was "+str(numbertoguess)+".")
```

You could just return score in both cases like so:

```
if numbertoguess == guess:
    print ("Great guess! You're correct.")
    int (score = score + 1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, the number was "+str(numbertoguess)+".")
return score
```

Also, this line may not be doing what you want:

```
int (score = score + 1)
```

There's no reason to [cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) this, just use this line:

```
score = score + 1
```

Or:

```
score += 1
```

One final note is the `GuessingGame` would be better styled like:

```
guessing_game
```

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works exactly how I want it to now. Your answer was thorough, easy to understand, and not at all rude about my inaccuracies, thanks a lot!